# Can a RNN make a joint prediction and if so, is this implementable in Python software like Tensorflow or Pytorch?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, recurrent-neural-network

I was wondering, can a RNN make a joint prediction (or predict two outputs at once)?  For example, let's say I want to predict tomorrow's weather.  I want to predict both temperature and humidity as a joint prediction.  For my specific case, I don't think it makes sense to build two models, one for humidity and one for temperature.

Is this something that is possible with the current free technology out there, and if so, is this able to be implemented in Keras/Tensorflow or Pytorch?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to state the obvious, an RNN with $N$ units outputs $N$ values for each step. (If you're using a model with a hidden state in addition to an output, such as [lstm](/questions/tagged/lstm), then there are $N$ hidden states as well.)

If you have two targets, one for temperature and one for humidity, you could use 1 or more dense layers to go from $N$ to 2 units, and arbitrarily assign one of those units to predict temperature and the other humidity.

Alternatively, you could do something like partition the RNN outputs. You could use an RNN with 2 units, and arbitrarily assign one of those units to predict temperature and the other humidity. (Of course, this "partition" strategy is actually a special case of a dense strategy using fixed binary weights, since the "partition" is the same as just using a binary mask.)

My assumption is that the RNN-then-dense strategy would work better, because restricting the RNN to just 2 units seems overly restrictive.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I should just get started instead of thinking about issues I might encounter.  The more I read, the more it seems like the structure of my NN (and basically how I can connect the nodes/layers) is very flexible.